# Pressing "Alt" key trigger textChanged signal on QtTextEdit in PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

Here is the script I have tested on PyQt5 5.7 on ubuntu :

```
pyt5 = True
import sys

if pyt5:
    from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    textedit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(parent=None)
else:
    from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    textedit = QtGui.QTextEdit(parent=None)

def printTextChanged():
    print('TextChanged')

textedit.textChanged.connect(printTextChanged)
textedit.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Then executing the file with pyqt5 and pressing the key **Alt**, it triggers the *textChanged* signal even if the text obviously did not changed. It is not the case when using pyqt4.

I imagine it is a bug. Does somebody has an idea to avoid this behavior?

Comment: I have tested it in PyQt5 5.9 and I do not observe that behavior, what version of PyQt5 do you have and what is your OS?

Comment: PyQt5 5.7 on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: You have tried another machine, maybe your keyboard is configured so that the Alt key performs some editing action.

Comment: Maybe, I will try that. I have also tried with the updated version of pyqt5 5.9, it has the same behavior.

Comment: I have tested it on Arch linux with PyQt5 5.9 and I do not have that behavior. I think it is the configuration of your pc.